# Is there a way to check for traffic tickets on a rental car before leaving Italy?

Tags: italy, car-rentals, fines

I want to know if it is possible to check for traffic tickets on a rental car during the period of the rental in Italy. I am talking about tickets where the driver is notified by letter, such as speeding, automated ZTL camera tickets..

I am asking the question because most rental car companies charge a fee to disclose the name of the driver when they get the traffic violation letter. Therefore, if I am able to pay the ticket straightaway, the rental company will never be notified.

Comment: I honestly don't think it's possible unless you call all police departments and municipalities you travel through. And even in that case they might just not know. Speeding is easily avoidable, ZTLs are a whole different story.  
Are there companies that don't charge you in event of a ticket?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no. There is no centralised system you can access, nor is there a way to ask the authorities. Even if you could ask, there is no guarantee that they would have the information anyways, since there is a processing time needed to receive and analyse all the traffic violation data. The only thing you can do is wait for the fine to be delivered. Legally this can take up to a maximum of 90 days from the date in which the offence was committed.

The only exception to this are some ZTL systems with online portals, which you can use to check when you accessed the ZTL and pay for passes. One example is the Milan Area C ZTL. I am not aware of others.